# Android navigation bar issue

Tags: android, android-layout, uinavigationbar

[image]

**Scenario**

I am facing a problem related to the navigation bar in google nexus.
In my fragment I have an Image view (being displayed from the local resoure, eg: cofee mug)
and a tag containing description (basically button view with text). Both the views are inside a layout.
the tag is positioned with certain margin from left and top in dp, so the tag would look like exactly below the image.

The coffee mug image has been sliced for the xhdpi resolution.

**Problem faced**

When the application is run on xhdpi device such as s3 the tag is exactly below the coffee mug image as expected. But when run on google nexus 3, containing navigation bar, the image is scaled rendered since the navigation bar consumes certain amount pixels.But for some reason my tag is mispositioned.

How can I ensure that the tag is not mispositioned? I appreciate if you could provide some suggestion.

Layout looks similar to below:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />


    <Button android:id="@+id/discoverTitle" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/tag_states"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#515151"/>
```

Image view is the coFfee mug image mentioned above and the button view is the tag (blue image). both are inside a relative layout parent with match parent for height and width.

Expected:

[image: actual]

Comment: How does your XML layout look like? How can we help you without knowing that?

Comment: have added sample code similar to actual implementation.

Comment: did you try put your xml in drawable-nodpi folder?

Comment: nope the image is inside the respective drawable folder. Because of the touch navigation bar the image is resized accordingly but the position of tag is little misplaced. also the above attached image is the not the actual implementation, its just representation of the scenarion. Pardon me as i cannot not share actual screenshot.

Comment: why dont u use the **layout_below** property to place the button exactly below the imageview..